# Can I create a CMOS AND gate with 2 serial n-type and 2 paralel p-type CMOS transistors?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, cmos

So I know that a CMOS AND gate is made with 2 parallel p-type transistors and 2 serial n-type transistors and an inverter on the output. But can we just make the AND gate similar to the NOR gate -instead to just use 2 serial n-type with 2 parallel p type. The truth table makes up an AND as far as I can see.
[image: Here is a schema of what I am saying]

Comment: Ask yourself: Is this design regenerative? If the input voltages are near the minimum logic high level (for example) will the output voltage still be a valid logic high (or even better, well above the input voltages)?

Comment: Are you essentially asking what happens if you swap the nMOS with the pMOS devices and vice versa where the nMOS is the pulldown and pMOS is the pullup? If so then... yeah... the circuit **won't** behave the same way...

Comment: @KingDuken, I think they're trying to get a minimalist AND gate rather than a NAND + inverter.

Comment: Why the p-type has to be in parallel and not in serial?

Answer (score 1):

The logic is correct, that does implement the AND function.   However, the output impedance is dependent on the input state (sinks more
current when inputs are F,F than when they are T, F).  This
results in odd behaviors that made timings uncertain, and
modern CMOS (CD4000B series) gates are almost all
two-stage (with a buffer inverter added) gates.

That reasoning does not apply to one-input (inverter) circuits,
and a few of those (CD4049UB) are still available,
but the two-stage gates have superior gain, so the general
run of off-the-shelf CMOS is all buffered.   Internal to
a complex device, the unbuffered variants are still useful
subcircuits.